# How to run playbook on my application server using sudo?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am writing a playbook for my Application tomcat node It will copy, deploy and stop/start tomcats.
I have a hop box serverA, another hop box serverB and tomcat node tomcatC. Manually using putty i use below steps to get on to the tomcat

1. Login to serverA using userId1
2. ssh to serverB using userId2
3. ssh to tomcatC using userId1
4. sudo to tomcat user.

Also I am able to directly ssh to tomcatC from serverA and my Ansible master is also serverA from where I am running the playbooks.

How do i run my playbook for this? Below is my playbook i am using as of now but it's not working.
`ansible-playbook -i my-inventory  my-V3.yml --tags=download,copy,deploy -e release_version=5.7 -e target_env=tomcatC -u userId1 --ask-pass`. AND my-v3.yml looks like below -

`hosts: '{{ target_env }}'
  #serial: 1
  remote_user: userId1
  become: yes
  become_user: tomcat`

Getting this Error NOW -

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
fatal: [tomcatC] => Missing become password

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user a command is run as like so:

```
- cron:
    name: "Clear Root Mail"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "22"
    job: "sudo rm /var/spool/mail/root"
    user: myuser
```

Or use become: true like so:

```
- name: Start Server
  shell: "nohup /home/myuser/StartServer.sh &"
  become: true
```

You can have shell scripts run the commands you need to run as well that ansible calls from the jump box you have. Your problem looks like you dont have the correct ssh key applied though.